# When using BT or emule, is there a way to see what files your peers are sharing?

Tags: bittorrent, emule

When using BT or emule, I can see a list of peers -- is there a way to see what files they are sharing as well?

Comment: Not in Bittorrent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel said, not possible in Bittorrent. NOR in emule. In eMule you can see what they have to share.. the so called 'file list', but that's all. That would be a really hard harm of privacy if one could see what the other person does.